# Posting feed on Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting a feed to facebook wall using the facebook graph via the php sdk.
Its working good as long as the link field is to an outside url.
If I change the link to my facebook app (which is what I need eventually), I get an exception, and the feed wont send.
How can I place a link to my app on the posted feed?

Thanks,
David

Comment: What is your code boss? please provide your code

Comment: Along with @Awais request, what is the **exception** you are getting?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, According to the latest settings its not allowed to post outside links.

If you want to still post, just disable "Stream post URL security" in your app settings.